# Construct large object in c# with excel values

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to create collection of arround 900 object, but constructor is taking too much time to read excel value, arround 4 minutes is necessary to construct whole entity. Is there a faster way ?
Below is object property

```
public class entityDataObject
{
    public string var1{ get; set; }
    public string var2 { get; set; }
    public string var3 { get; set; }
    public string var4 { get; set; }
    public string var5 { get; set; }
    public string var6{ get; set; }
    public string var7{ get; set; }
    public string var8{ get; set; }
    public string var9{ get; set; }
    public string var10{ get; set; }
    public string var11{ get; set; }
    public string var12{ get; set; }
}
```

then I iterate my excel values into below.

```
for (int i = firstRow + 1; i <= lastRow; i++)
{
    entityDataObject newObject = (new entityDataObject()
    {
        var1= currentws.Cells[i, Column1].Value.ToString(),
        var2= currentws.Cells[i, Column2].Value.ToString(),
        var3= currentws.Cells[i, Column3].Value.ToString(),
        var4= currentws.Cells[i, Column4].Value.ToString(),
        var5= currentws.Cells[i, Column5].Value.ToString(),
        var6= currentws.Cells[i, Column6].Value.ToString(),
        var7= currentws.Cells[i, Column7].Value.ToString(),
        var8= currentws.Cells[i, Column8].Value.ToString(),
        var9= currentws.Cells[i, Column9].Value.ToString(),
        var10= currentws.Cells[i, Column10].Value.ToString(),
        var11= currentws.Cells[i, Column11].Value.ToString(),
        var12= currentws.Cells[i, Column12].Value.ToString(),
    });

    entityCollection.Add(newObject);

};

return entityCollection;
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that reads the excel file we can't know if it can be improved. Are you sure it is the culprit?

Comment: Basically, code is only opening a workbook and naming worksheet as "currentws", where the values stand

Comment: I've used the `ExcelDataReader` Nuget package in the past and found it to be pretty performant. Are you able to use that?

Comment: would it help to construct my above objects faster ?

Comment: I've used it to parse an Excel file with >10000 into a list of complex objects in <5s, so it's pretty fast. I'll post an answer with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not constructing the objects, the problem is that Excel automation is slow. Automation is when you have to open an Excel instance to work with the worksheet, i.e., this is when you are using Office Interop.

Use a library that doesn't need Microsoft Office to be installed. E.g., the open source library [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) written in C# or [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) (see @Daevin's comments).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not with building the objects, the problem is most likely due to the speed of the Excel file reader being used. The sample below uses the `ExcelDataReader` Nuget package (I have no affiliation, I've only used it in the past) which I've found to be very performant, especially compared to Microsoft's Office interop libraries.

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("[filePath]"))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs))
    {
        var workbook = reader.AsDataSet();
        var worksheet = workbook.Tables[0];

        for (var i = 1; i < worksheet.Rows.Count; i++) // start at 1 to skip header
        {
            var dataRow = worksheet.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
            
            var newObj = new EntityDataObject()
            {
                // populate your object from dataRow
            };
            entityCollection.Add(newObj);
        }

        return entityCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but changing whole code to get excel values would be painful in my program.
Thus i managed to find another solution that i'll post

Comment: @ThibaultKm no need to be sorry, just consider "how painful would it be to convert this over to a much faster model?" vs "how painful is it to have to wait 4min every time I run this?" and make the decision off that :) and consider how much faster this would be: I've parsed an Excel file well over 10x larger than yours ~50x faster than your way.

Comment: indeed that's good point !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who helped, i managed to find a solution that allow me not to change whole code.
The idea is to get whole workbook value in an object as below

```
object[,] virtualCells = new object[lastRow, maxColumnValue];
virtualCells =currentws.Range[currentws.Cells[firstRow,minColumnValue],
              currentws.Cells[lastRow, maxColumnValue]].value;
```

then just parsing the data within is. It takes 4ms, very fast.

```
for (int i = firstRow + 1; i <= lastRow; i++)
{
    entityDataObject newObject = (new entityDataObject()
    {
        var1= virtualCells[i, Column1].Value.ToString(),
        var2= virtualCells[i, Column2].Value.ToString(),
        var3= virtualCells[i, Column3].Value.ToString(),
        var4= virtualCells[i, Column4].Value.ToString(),
        var5= virtualCells[i, Column5].Value.ToString(),
        var6= virtualCells[i, Column6].Value.ToString(),
        var7= virtualCells[i, Column7].Value.ToString(),
        var8= virtualCells[i, Column8].Value.ToString(),
        var9= virtualCells[i, Column9].Value.ToString(),
        var10= virtualCells[i, Column10].Value.ToString(),
        var11= virtualCells[i, Column11].Value.ToString(),
        var12= virtualCells[i, Column12].Value.ToString(),
    });

    entityCollection.Add(newObject);

};
```

return entityCollection;